# How can I get the covariance result cumulatively?

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics

I am trying to derive the covariance results for a $n \times 4$ matrix where $n$ is an arbitrary number.

I am trying to derive the covariance for each row cumulatively.
For example, I am trying to derive the covariance for this matrix from row 1 to row 2, then from row 1 to 3, row 1 to 4, row 1 to 5, and so on such as:

```
result[i_] := Covariance[{{rc1[[1 ;; i]]}, {rc2[[1 ;; i]]}, 
                          {rc2[[1 ;; i]]}, {rc2[[1 ;; i]]}}]
```

where `rc1`, `rc2`, `rc3`, `rc4` are arbitrary list of numbers with only one column.

I tried this code and it does not seem to work as well but I am trying to do the work something like this.

I would appreciate if I could get help on this.
Thank you.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `n = 5;
rc = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 4}];
Table[ Covariance[rc[[1 ;; i]]], {i, 2, n}]`

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Actually, I am trying to produce covariance results for a matrix which has four columns with an arbitrary number of rows which can be any. Therefore, the 4 columns should contain all different rows..

Comment: isn't that what I wrote?  `n` is number of rows.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are right. However, when I am trying to construct one matrix with four columns using the list from rc1, rc2, rc3, rc4, then is it correct to construct like {rc1,rc2,rc3,rc4}? I think combining like this will solve the problem as your example shows.

Comment: For example, when I derive the covariance results using four lists from row 1 to row 3 such as `Covariance[{rc1[[1 ;; 3]], rc2[[1 ;; 3]], rc3[[1 ;; 3]], 
  rc4[[1 ;; 3]]}]` the result gives 3 rows and 3 columns where I am expecting just 3 rows. But it is very strange that when I execute the command `{rc1[[1 ;; 3]], rc2[[1 ;; 3]], rc3[[1 ;; 3]], rc4[[1 ;; 3]]}` it gives out 3 rows and 4 columns as expected. May I know how I can resolve this?

Comment: Another example is that when I make this into matrix form and call this rcc like `rcc = MatrixForm[{rc1[[1 ;; 3]], rc2[[1 ;; 3]], rc3[[1 ;; 3]], 
   rc4[[1 ;; 3]]}]` and use this to produce covariance results like `Covariance[rcc]`, it gives error since it seems to need another element but I would like to know how I can resolve this problem..